# pandas remove records conditionally based on records count of groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Country':['UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK'],
    'Product':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D'],
            'Week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
       'val': [5,4,3,1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country','Product','Week', 'val'])

print(df2)
```

[image]

and mapping dataframe

```
mapping = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','C'],'Product1':['B','D']}, columns = ['Product','Product1'])
```

[image]

and i wanted to compare products as per mapping.  product A data should match with product B data.. the logic is product A number of records is 4 so product B records also should be 4 and those 4 records should be from the week number before and after form last week number of product A and including the last week number. so before 1 week of week number 4 i.e. 3rd week and after 2 weeks of week number 4 i.e 5,6 and week 4 data.

similarly product C number of records is 3 so product D records also should be 3 and those records before and after last week number of product C. so product c last week number 3 so product D records will be week number 2,3,4.

wanted data frame will be like below i wanted to remove those yellow records

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following function selecting rows from *df*, for products from
the current *row* in *mapping*:

```
def selRows(row, df):
    rows_1 = df[df.Product == row.Product]
    nr_1 = rows_1.index.size
    lastWk_1 = rows_1.Week.iat[-1]
    rows_2 = df[df.Product.eq(row.Product1) & df.Week.ge(lastWk_1 - 1)].iloc[:nr_1]
    return pd.concat([rows_1, rows_2])
```

Then call it the following way:

```
result = pd.concat([ selRows(row, grp)
    for _, grp in df2.groupby(['Country'])
        for _, row in mapping.iterrows() ])
```

The list comprehension above creates a list on DataFrames - results of
calls of *selRows* on:

- each group of rows from *df2*, for consecutive countries (the outer loop),
- each row from *mapping* (the inner loop).

Then *concat* concatenates all of them into a single DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the output is not matching with wanted output. i want to deselect those yellow highlighted rows but your function selecting those rows.could you please check

Comment: i want to include 3,4,5,6 week numbers only in output data frame but in your function it will give 1,2,3,5 .and same for product D 2,3,4 week numbers only but in your function it will return 1,2,4

Comment: I changed a little my solution. Rows with *Product1* should be from weeks:
1. Starting from one week before the final week for *Product*.
2. With no upper limit.
3. But the total number of these rows should be equal to the number of
rows for *Product*.

Comment: Thanks it helped on this data. But in my real data i have many countries and products. It's not working for other countries data. Suppose if i have same data with other country say US also in same dataframe. So total records wil be 42 in df2. Then it's not giving correct results. Can you please suggest how to do same thing if we have multiple countries in same dataframe.

Comment: I corrected my solution, to take into accout the fact that what you described should be executed on each group of rows, for particular country.

Comment: Thanks this helped..i just tried to give multiple variables say country and city in group by..it's throwing """IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0""" ...this code only works for one variable?

Comment: Too much additional levels of complication, not mentioned in the initial content of your post. This is a good material for **another** question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution first create mapped column by `mapping` DataFrame and create dictionaries for mapping for length and last (maximal) value by groups by `Country` and `Product`:

```
df2['mapp'] = df2['Product'].map(mapping.set_index('Product1')['Product'])
df1 = df2.groupby(['Country','Product'])['Week'].agg(['max','size'])

#subtracted 1 for last previous value
dprev = df1['max'].sub(1).to_dict()
dlen = df1['size'].to_dict()
print(dlen)
{('UK', 'A'): 4, ('UK', 'B'): 8, ('UK', 'C'): 3, ('UK', 'D'): 6}
```

Then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) values of dict and filter out less values, then filter by second dictionary by lengths with [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df3 = (df2[df2[['Country','mapp']].apply(tuple, 1).map(dprev) <= df2['Week']]
            .groupby(['Country','mapp'])
            .apply(lambda x: x.head(dlen.get(x.name))))

print(df3)
                Country Product  Week  val mapp
Country mapp                                   
UK      A    6       UK       B     3    7    A
             7       UK       B     4    8    A
             8       UK       B     5    9    A
             9       UK       B     6   10    A
        C    16      UK       D     2    6    C
             17      UK       D     3    7    C
             18      UK       D     4    8    C
```

Then filter original rows unmatched `mapping['Product1']`, add new `df3` and sorting:

```
df = (df2[~df2['Product'].isin(mapping['Product1'])]
           .append(df3, ignore_index=True)
           .sort_values(['Country','Product'])
           .drop('mapp', axis=1))
print(df)
   Country Product  Week  val
0       UK       A     1    5
1       UK       A     2    4
2       UK       A     3    3
3       UK       A     4    1
7       UK       B     3    7
8       UK       B     4    8
9       UK       B     5    9
10      UK       B     6   10
4       UK       C     1    5
5       UK       C     2    5
6       UK       C     3    5
11      UK       D     2    6
12      UK       D     3    7
13      UK       D     4    8
```